# Скачать файл с произношением текста и проговорить текст

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте, делаю программу-словарь для изучения иностранных языков. Хочу сделать следующее: в базе хранить файл с произношением самого слова/выражения, которое хочу взять у гугла, подскажите? как мне

1. "проговорить" слово в режиме реального времени с гугла (или другого сервиса)
2. как скачать mp3 указанного слова и добавить в базу и потом, находясь оффлайн, их слушать.

Если есть русскоязычные решения, подскажите, пожалуйста, т.к. в английском пока не силён.(хотя и на английском можно :) ).

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

```
var input = "hello world";

var url_fmt = "http://translate.google.com/" +
                "translate_tts?ie=UTF-8" +
                "&q={0}" +
                "&tl=en" +
                "&total=1" +
                "&idx=0" +
                "&textlen={1}" +
                "&prev=input";
var url = string.Format(url_fmt, WebUtility.HtmlEncode(input), input.Length);

var data = new WebClient().DownloadData(url);

using (var file = File.OpenWrite("audio.mpeg"))
{
    file.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

"проговорить" слово можно с помощью библиотеки NAudio, например